# Android - Connected Tests Results Directory

Tags: android, testing, output

I have an android project where I run normal unit tests as well as instrumented tests.

---

Now the thing is that the results of the

- **unit tests** are stored in `build/reports/tests` (`./debug` or `./release`)
- **instrumented tests** are stored in `build/outputs/connected`

---

Is it somehow possible to change the result directory of the instrumented tests to `build/reports/tests/connected`?

Thank you already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer myself, To change the directory for instrumented tests use:

```
android {
    testOptions {
        reportDir = "$project.buildDir/reports"
        resultsDir = "$project.buildDir/test-results"
    }

    # Or for lint if needed
    lintOptions {
        htmlOutput = file("$project.buildDir/reports/lint/LINT-results.html")
        xmlOutput = file("$project.buildDir/test-results/lint/LINT-results.xml")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me. No folder is created after adding this code when using grade test. Using latest gradle version coming bundled with latest stable Android Studio on Win10

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be more reliable:

```
android {

    [...]

    testOptions {
        if (project.hasProperty("customResultsDir")) {
            resultsDir "${customResultsDir}"
        }
        if (project.hasProperty("customReportDir")) {
            reportDir "${customReportDir}"
        }
    }
}
```

There is the bonus that it checks if the property is passed before trying to use it (a good practice). But the real interesting part is that this ways you are interpolating a closure instead of a variable - the differences allow further possibilities (check [string interpolation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_string_interpolation) and [closure interpolation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_special_case_of_interpolating_closure_expressions)).

On my scenario, only by using the closure did I manage to have the properties to populate at the exact time.